# kendu ui datasource read event has null request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, kendo-mobile

I have an Kendo UI scheduler widget on mobile page, which as you can see has a datasource read event.

```
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    ...
    dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
            url: "http://mydomain.com/api/Schedule/Tasks_Read",
            dataType: "jsonp"
            },
...
});
```

When the read event is called it sends the request as

```
http://mydomain.com/api/Schedule/Tasks_Read?callback=jQuery1910528280699858442_1396259085815&_=1396259085816
```

the problem is that when the webapi get method gets the request, the **[DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request** parameter is null.

```
[HttpGet]
        public DataSourceResult Tasks_Read(
            [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        //,DateTime startDate)
        {
            using (scApp = new ScheduleControllerApplication())
            {
...
}
}
```

Can somebody clue me into why the request parameter is null?

I have a scheduler on a MVC4 page and it works fine and has the same querystring **jquery** addition.

**MY SOLUTION** - By no means let this stop you from answering if you have diferent approach.
Being that this call was from a mobile source i changed the httpget signature

```
[HttpGet]
        public string Tasks_Read(
            string request)
        {
            using (scApp = new ScheduleControllerApplication())
            {
...
}
}
```

and it worked and returned the 2 jQuery items i was expecting.