# DataSourceRequest always null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I am trying to use Kendo's server side paging/filtering/sorting, and as of now I'm doing it as follows:

datasource is :

```
var QueueMessages = {
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "api/QueueMessages/wut",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: ........
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    filter: ....
};
```

and in the api controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("wut")]
    public DataSourceResult wut([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return messages.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    }
```

However, `DataSourceRequest request` is always `null`

i have tried some solutions i found to similar problems looking for missing .js, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758815/kendu-ui-datasource-read-event-has-null-request) to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Creating `datasource` should be like this :

```
var QueueMessages = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "api/QueueMessages/wut",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: ........
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    filter: ....
});
```

you've missed  **new kendo.data.DataSource**

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by using the following:

```
public DataSourceResult Get([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceREquestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
{
   // return your data
}
```

So, it appears that Kendo UI is *really* looking for the 
`System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder` class to bind the request to your controller. So, if you are not using that class to bind the request, it will be null. Please note that there is a `ModelBinder` attribute class, do not use this as the result will also be null.

Here is the documentation that I am using (even though it's the C# wrapper), it might be useful one day: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editing/webapi-editing?_ga=2.245906311.2036381207.1547477384-1442120099.1541630215 [web api documentation]

I hope this helps.